# Why Am I getting "Login error" on Node mailer?

Tags: node.js, nodemailer

I was trying to send an email using Node mailer, but kept getting invalid login error.
I want to send an email when user sign up.

I enabled 2-factor verification and Created an app for this purpose. I already got 16 digit password for this app.
[Created an app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vvcYt.png)

here is the error I am getting

```
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i10-20020a05640200ca00b0050bd9d3ddf3sm4737563edu.42 - gsmtp
project/node_modules/nodemailer/lib/smtp-connection/index.js:193:44)
    at TLSSocket.emit (node:events:512:28)
    at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:324:12)
    at readableAddChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:297:9)
    at Readable.push (node:internal/streams/readable:234:10) {
  code: 'EAUTH',
  response: '535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n' +
    '535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials i10-20020a05640200ca00b0050bd9d3ddf3sm4737563edu.42 - gsmtp',
  responseCode: 535,
  command: 'AUTH PLAIN'
}
```

Here is my code.

```
const nodemailer = require("nodemailer");
const sender = process.env.EMAIL_NAME;
const passsword = process.env.EMAIL_PASSWORD;

exports.confrimEmail = (name, recieverEmail) => {
  const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: "gmail",
    host: "smtp.gmail.com",
    auth: {
      user: sender,
      pass: passsword,
    },
  });

  const mailOptions = {
    from: sender,
    to: recieverEmail,
    subject: "Confirm Your Email Address for AASTU-GDSC Inventory API",
    text: `Dear ${name}, \n
           Thank you for signing up for the AASTU-GDSC Inventory API!\n
           We are excited to have you join our community and
           can't wait to see what you will create with our API.
           To complete your registration, we need to confirm your email address.\nPlease click on the link below to verify your email address:\n
           http://localhost:3001/api/users/confrimed
           `,
  };

  transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
      console.log(error);
    } else {
      console.log(mailOptions.from);
      console.log(mailOptions.to);
      console.log(mailOptions.text);
      console.log("Email sent:" + info.response);
    }
  });
};
```